# How to display my custom block after view.phtml, using XML layout updates only?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, layout-update

I can append my block to content block, by using reference, with this layout update:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view> 
        <reference name="content"> 
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="filtereduseditems" before="-">
                <action method ="getUsedItemsInCategory">
                </action>
            </block>

            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="filterednewitems" after="-">
                <action method ="getNewItemsInCategory">
                </action>
            </block>

            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="filteredremainderitems" after="-">
                <action method ="getRemainderItemsInCategory">
                </action>
            </block>


        </reference> 
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

But it displays before view.phtml. I want it to be displayed after view.phtml, which already exists. How can I do that? I tried these references:

```
<reference name="category.products"> 
<reference name="product_list"> 
<reference name="product_list.name.after"> 
<reference name="product_list.after">
```

and it didn't work, the block can only be displayed on:

```
<reference name="content">
```

. What else can I try? I want my block (3 instances of it) appended to the end of (name=)'content' block, after view.phtml, or appended to view.phtml, but without changing the view.phtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `product_list` then write this code in your `catalog/product/list.phtml` file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('filtereduseditems'); ?>
```

And If you are using `category.products` then add above code in `catalog/layer/view.phtml` file

Comment: Thanks. This is one way to do it. I want to do it completely with xml updates, without changing the list.phtml and view.phtml files.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic you can use `product_list.after` reference  name but it will add your block after the product listing, otherwise there is no default block in list page for your problem

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic if you want directly via xml then your refreance block should be  type with ` block type="core/text_list" `

Comment: It doesn't even work on core/text_list. I tried to put it on:
product_list.name.after
and it doesn't work.

Comment: are you using color swatches ?

Comment: No, just a simple product.

Comment: How can I use $this -> getChildHtml('filtereduseditems); to output filtereditems block from inside list.phtml? What XML do I have to write and where?

Comment: I dont Understand what you said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49140/discussion-between-vladimir-despotovic-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `footer_before` reference

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view> 
        <reference name="footer_before"> 
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="filtereduseditems">
                <action method="getUsedItemsInCategory">
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="filterednewitems">
                <action method="getNewItemsInCategory">
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="filteredremainderitems">
                <action method="getRemainderItemsInCategory">
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference> 
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```